# Unique configuration for a website in IIS

Tags: web-server, iis-6, website

I am currently running IIS version 6 and desire to create a website with the ending extension of .com/espanol. I have been asked however to add a tilde over the n in espanol.

Can this be done? if so, how do I go about completing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a directory named `español` in your site.  Simple as that.

Comment: Yeah I understand that part. But how on earth do I get the tilde over the n?

Comment: On Windows, on a US keyboard?  Alt-164.

Comment: On a side note. Num Lock must be on.